# How to start activity with specific fragment but activity has no dependency on fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I want to start an activity which is a generic fragment host, and the activity can show whatever fragment I want to pass to it. I know I can do some `switch-case` or `if-else` and use some `String` or int from `Intent` to create corresponding `Fragment`. But this will have dependency on the concrete `Fragment`, I'm wondering if there is anyway to implement this **without having dependency on the concrete fragment**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here should a design pattern be adopted, e.g. [`FactoryMethod`](https://www.oodesign.com/factory-method-pattern.html) , to decouple the dependency between host `Activity` and each individual `Fragment`. Roughly it can be diagrammed as below:

[image]

In above class diagram, your host activity will only depend on the factory instead of each individual fragment.

**Notes:**

1. The `Fragment createFragment(String fragmentDescriptor)` is a **static** method and the return type is the parent class `Fragment`, **NOT** the subtypes.
2. The Fragment creation logic shall be handled inside the factory so that your host activity will be freed of this creation logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jetpack navigation:

```
NavController().navigate(fragmentId)
```

or more complicated way with options depends on what you need

```
NavController().navigate(fragmentUri, navOptions)
```